# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a little problem. I'm doing the event ready, with an event handler, but I come across this error:

```
    client.user.setPresence({
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null
```

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, here is the code:

```js
const mongo = require('../../mongo');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const messageCount = require('../../message-counter')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = async (Discord, client) => {
    let serverIn = client.guilds.cache.size;
    console.log('[INFO] Doose is online');
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "dnd",
        activity: {
            name: `${serverIn} servers! | BETA | d.help`,
            type: "WATCHING"
        }
    });

    console.log('[INFO] Connected to MongoDB')

    messageCount(client)
};
```

**MUST READ: Extra Info**

> Using discord.js V13

Comment: You don't show how you're calling that function. `client.user` is definitely `null`. Are you passing in the client?

Comment: To avoid breaking code when `client` is `undefined`. Try to wrap your function with `if(client && client.user)`.

Comment: wdym? sorry, i'm new to this. can you explain?

Comment: btw i updated the code. this time is shows: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null

Answer (score 2):

Presence can be set via the `options` parameter in the `Discord.Client(options)` constructor like so:

```js
const client = new Client({
    presence: {
        status: 'online',
        afk: false,
        activities: [{
            name: ...,
            type: ...,
        }],
    },
    intents: [...],
    partials: [...],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**This should help !!**

```
client.on('ready', () => {

client.user.setActivity(`!help || ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers `, { type: "LISTENING" })
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);

})
```

**and for the other , you can use something like this ⬇️**

```
client.user.setPresence({
                status: "idle"
            })
```